# Cadastro de Produtos com Select Multiple não insere todos selecionados

Tags: php, pdo

Os itens cadastrados tem vários sabores, chocolate, morango, baunilha, etc, e cada um é inserido por `select multiple` no cadastro, ele é salvo como "chocolate" porém os outros sabores selecionados não são inseridos.

**Código PHP**

```
 if ( ! isset( $_POST ) || empty( $_POST ) ) {
    echo '.';
    echo '<script>';
        echo "Materialize.toast('Impossível continuar!', 4000, 'rounded black');";
        echo '$(".success_v2").removeClass("more");
        $(".success_v2").removeClass("auth");
        $(".loader").hide();
        </script>';
    exit;
}
foreach ( $_POST as $chave => $valor ) {
    $$chave = $valor;
    if ( empty( $valor ) ) {
        echo '.';
        echo '<script>';
        echo "Materialize.toast('Existe campo em branco', 4000, 'rounded red');";
        echo '$(".success_v2").removeClass("more");
        $(".success_v2").removeClass("auth");
        $(".loader").hide();
        </script>';
    }
}
if (   
    ! isset( $nome )
    || ! isset( $marca     )
    || ! isset( $categoria     )
    || ! isset( $peso     )
    || ! isset( $sabor     )
    || ! isset( $prod_destaque     )
    || ! isset( $preco     )
    || ! isset( $codigo     )
    || ! isset( $prod_desconto     )
    || ! isset( $dob     )

) {
    echo '.';
    echo '<script>';
        echo "Materialize.toast('Ainda há campos vázios.', 4000, 'rounded red');";
        echo '$(".success_v2").removeClass("more");
        $(".success_v2").removeClass("auth");
        $(".loader").hide();
        </script>';
    exit;
}
$prepara = $conexao_pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `produtos` (`nome`,`nome_iso`,`cod`,`marca`,`categoria`,`status`,`preco`,`desconto`,`data`,`chns`,`autor`,`descricao`,`peso`,`sabores`,`cover`,`prod_destaque`,`prod_desconto`,`link`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$verifica = $prepara->execute(
    array(
        $nome,
        $nome_cl,
        $codigo,
        $marca,
        $categoria,
        $dob,
        $preco,
        $desconto,
        $data,
        $chns,
        $autor,
        $descricao,
        $peso,
        $sabor,
        $novo_nome_imagem,
        $prod_destaque,
        $prod_desconto,
        $link_final
    )
);
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="seleciona" name="sabor" multiple="">
    <option disabled selected>Selecione o Sabor</option>
    <option value="chocolate">chocolate</option>
    <option value="morango">morango</option>
    <option value="baunilha">baunilha</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duas coisas precisam ser concertadas. Primeiro alterar o atributo name da tag select para `name="sabor[]"` (Isso vai permitir a correta deserialização para a super global `$_POST`). E segundo, iterar sobre o array `$_POST['sabor']` para capturar todos os sabores escolhidos.

No html fica:

```
<select class="seleciona" name="sabor[]" multiple="">
    <option disabled selected>Selecione o Sabor</option>
    <option value="chocolate">chocolate</option>
    <option value="morango">morango</option>
    <option value="baunilha">baunilha</option>
</select>
```

No php deve ser feito (após a validação e antes do insert que você já faz) um laço for para capturar todos os sabores. Aqui há um detalhe importante: como você vai querer salvar todos esses sabores? Simplesmente como uma unica string? Ou vai salvar em uma relação 1 para muitos?

Nesse exemplo vou colocar tudo como uma string unica. Então fica:

```
$sabor = '';
foreach($_POST['sabor'] as $s){
    $sabor .= ',' . $s;
}
//para remover a primeira virgula
$sabor = ltrim($sabor, ',');
```

Quando você for ler esse valor da base de dados será retornada uma string similar a `sabor 1, sabor 2, sabor 3, ...`.

Como pode ser complicado iterar sobre esses valores posteriormente você poderia considerar usar as funções [serialize](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.serialize.php) e [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unserialize.php). A primeira converte a estrutura de um vetor para string, e a segunda pode ser usada para reverter essa operação, ou seja, transformar de novo em um array.

## Exemplo de serialize e unserialize

```
<?php
//isso viria de $_POST['sabor']
$sabores = ['sabor1' => 'valor1', 'sabor2' => 'valor2'];
var_dump($sabores);
//imprime um vetor
/*
array(2) { ["sabor1"]=> string(6) "valor1" ["sabor2"]=> string(6) "valor2" }
*/

$serializeSabores = serialize($sabores);
//você poderia salvar a string $serializeSabores no banco
var_dump($serializeSabores);
//imprime uma string (vetor serializado)
/*
string(58) "a:2:{s:6:"sabor1";s:6:"valor1";s:6:"sabor2";s:6:"valor2";}"
*/

//para deserializar. Isso viria do banco como string
$unserializeSabores = unserialize($serializeSabores);
var_dump($unserializeSabores);
//imprime um vetor (string deserializada)
/*
array(2) { ["sabor1"]=> string(6) "valor1" ["sabor2"]=> string(6) "valor2" } 
*/

?>
```

Comment: cara, tudo me ajudou muito. Mas só estou tendo dificuldade com o serialize e unserialize, eu não manjo muito de php, mas oque eu sei eu consigo me virar. Se vc não se importar, poderia me dar um exemplo desse serialize ou unserialize para o select?

Comment: @ThomasFranklin editei a resposta para acrescentar esse exemplo.

Comment: obrigado pela explicação, vou estudar melhor a utilização de como utilizar o retorno do serialize/unserialize quando ficar mais tranquilo com o tempo. Eu fiz um código muito louco que deu certo usando `explode`, array `offset` e `if`.